# Mysql query based on 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql table named **new_test2** and **keywordssector**.
Table **new_test2** has the fields *title*, *noticeText* and *sectoradd*.
And table named **keywordssector** has 2 fields *keywords* and *sector*.

I am trying to run the below mentioned script to search for words mentioned in the field *keywords* (in table **keywordssector**) in the fields *title* and *noticeText* in the table **new_test2** and add the sector/s codes (separated by commas) mentioned in *sector* of table **keywordssector** to column *sectoradd* mentioned in table **new_test2**.

However I am getting the error - **#1054 - Unknown column 'keywordssector.keywords' in 'where clause'**. Even though the column *keywords* is present in the table **keywordssector**. Where am I goofing up?

```
UPDATE new_test2
SET sectoradd = CONCAT_WS(',', sectoradd, keywordssector.sector)
WHERE (
    new_test2.title LIKE CONCAT('%', (SELECT keywords FROM keywordssector WHERE keywordssector.keywords IS NOT NULL), '%')
    OR new_test2.noticeText LIKE CONCAT('%', (SELECT keywords FROM keywordssector WHERE keywordssector.keywords IS NOT NULL), '%')
) AND keywordssector.sector IS NOT NULL;`
```

Another one I tried without success - same error

```
UPDATE new_test2
SET sectoradd = CONCAT_WS(',', sectoradd, sector)
WHERE (
    new_test2.title LIKE CONCAT('%', keywordssector.keywords, '%')
    OR new_test2.noticeText LIKE CONCAT('%', keywordssector.keywords, '%')
) AND keywordssector.sector IS NOT NULL
  AND new_test2.sectoradd NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', sector, '%')
JOIN keywordssector ON (new_test2.title LIKE CONCAT('%', keywordssector.keywords, '%')
                        OR new_test2.noticeText LIKE CONCAT('%', keywordssector.keywords, '%'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the `keywordssector` table in the WHERE clause without actually joining it with the `new_test2` table. In your current query, the `keywordssector` table is not included in the FROM clause or joined in any way, which is why MySQL is unable to recognize the `keywordssector`.`keywords` column.

This query should be working properly:

```
UPDATE new_test2
JOIN keywordssector ON (
    new_test2.title LIKE CONCAT('%', keywordssector.keywords, '%')
    OR new_test2.noticeText LIKE CONCAT('%', keywordssector.keywords, '%')
)
SET new_test2.sectoradd = CONCAT_WS(',', new_test2.sectoradd, keywordssector.sector)
WHERE keywordssector.sector IS NOT NULL
  AND new_test2.sectoradd NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', keywordssector.sector, '%');
```

Comment: I have uploaded 20000 records in the new_test2 table for testing purpose. The actual number would be around 3 million. And the keywordssector table has 5100 records. After more than 20 minutes of running the above, I get the following error message.

_Error in processing request
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Error (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status_.

Comment: @GurusGuru how many records are you expecting to get updated? Probably you can run the `SELECT` statement first to realize how many rows gets affected. Maybe selecting such rows is low performant (you're doing LIKE with `%` on both sides which does not allow you to use indexes).

Comment: new_test2 table would have about 3 million records and the keywordssector table has 5100 records.
A typical entry of keywordssector table is - _talent management_ (**keywords**) _8406_ (**sector**)